# How to trace back bounced messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a web services which allows me to send messages via office 365 hosted service. So far all works fine. But there is cases when an email bounces and I would like to mark that email bounced / undelivered in my CRM. In some cases the remote host returns undelivered: and the original subject as well as the email address it was send to. In case of google addresses this is not the case. So I can’t parse the subject to get the original message. Is there anywhere in the body or header any info which I could use to find the originating message that was not delivered ?

Answer (score 1):

The In-reply-to header of the bounce message should contain the original InternetMessageId of the Message you Sent message. You can either use the InternetMessageHeaders or get the SingleValueExtendedProperties property for that header eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/MailFolders('Inbox')/messages/?$select=ReceivedDateTime,Sender,Subject,IsRead,inferenceClassification,InternetMessageId,parentFolderId,hasAttachments,webLink&$Top=10&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq 'String 0x1042')
```

Encoded version for the Graph Explorer preview

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/MailFolders('Inbox')/messages/?$select=ReceivedDateTime%2cSender%2cSubject%2cIsRead%2cinferenceClassification%2cInternetMessageId%2cparentFolderId%2chasAttachments%2cwebLink&$Top=10&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties(%24filter%3dId+eq+%27String+0x1042%27)
```

Comment: Using the sample above I get an error parsing select and expand failed. And under code snippet I get startindex can not be less than zero parameter name startIndex

Comment: The original worked fined for me in the Microsoft Graph explorer, however I tired it in the preview version and got the same error you described, actually any SingleValueExtendedProperties query in the preview version that wasn't encoded correctly gave the same error (looking at the request in fiddler the URL was getting really munged by the client side). I included a encoded version that seems to work okay in the Graph explorer preview.

Comment: I will try and let you know. One interesting thing I found is when I use the internetmessageid when I receive a subscription notification there is cases when I use a bogus address in google that I can not find the send message it’s in my send folder but when I look at headers in outlook it’s blank so that’s quite strange

Comment: ok i have tracked this feedback on Graph Explorer and escalted to the team. thanks for sharing this.